# Can you specify use site variance in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

Does C# have the equivalent of Java's wildcards? I know C# has declaration site variance. However, I wonder if the language offers an option to specify use-site variance. Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

```cs
class Parent {}
class Child : Parent {}
class Grandchild : Child {}

interface IProducer<out T>
{
    T produces();
}

interface IConsumer<in T>
{
    void consumes(T p);
}

class Collection<T> : IProducer<T>, IConsumer<T>
where T:new()
{
    private readonly T _v;

    public Collection()
    {
        _v = new T();
    }

    public T produces()
    {
        return _v;
    }

    public void consumes(T p)
    {
        //
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Collection<Child> coll = new Collection<Child>(); // Invariance
        
        IProducer<Parent> producer = coll; // Producer using declaration site variance and segregating by interface
        IConsumer<Grandchild> consumer = coll; // Consumer using declaration site variance and segregating by interface
        
        // Equivalent of Collection<? extends Parent> producer = coll; ?
        // Equivalent of Collection<? super Grandchild> producer = coll; ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, C# only supports declaration site variance.